# Database design issue, should i prevent crossing relations?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a database that seems to be challenging to my knowledge on database design.
I will try to explain and then I will ask the question.

I have a list of companies that have interact with the system and those companies can operate within my country and only my country, all the companies are dedicated to fishing activities. Those companies can have product providers or just fish by themselves. Those providers can operate in any country. The products bought from providers (most of them are frozen fish) can also come from any country and it is not necessarily the provider's country.
Of course I have a country table with the default value set to my country, that table is also referenced by providers and products.

[image: This is a very simplified version of my data model]

Well, with this design, there is no way to avoid relationships crossing. But my real question are,

1. is it a good practice to allow this to happen?
2. If not, how should i redesign it to fix it?
3. If yes, why everyone tells me to prevent this kind of relations?

Thanks!

Comment: by crossing you mean graphically crossing? because the user table can be moved to sit between provider and product and thus prevent a line cross.

Comment: Btw, the user.id_country is a varchar(100) whereas it should be an int.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it could be in the middle, basically what i mean is that all the tables USE the country table and from what i heard i should try to avoid this type of situations, but i don't see that possible.

Comment: Yeah, it was a mistake when i was building this model fast, sorry.

Comment: I don't see why that should be necessary; if all those entities each should have their own country then this is exactly what you need.

Comment: So basically, this design is correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me, but let's see what others have to say about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's analyse the situation:

> Those companies can operate within my country and only my country

I'm assuming the companies are represented by the `user` table; technically they wouldn't need a country, but looking ahead you may want to have companies from other countries.

> Those providers can operate in any country.

Okay, so `provider` definitely needs their own country field.

> The products bought from providers (most of them are frozen fish) can also come from any country and it is not necessarily the provider's country.

So `product` also needs their own country field.

Basically, you will want to represent a product from country X, bought from a provider of country Y and delivered by company from country Z. The model you have designed seems to reflect those relationships correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your database design should be OK. Something that need to defined with different country should have to be. There is no something "crossing" logically with it.

The one thing you should avoid in database design is **Circular Relation** which is A need B, B need C and C need A.

Comment: So, basically this kind of design is ok if one table is required by other tables, but it is not a circular design?

Comment: The one easy way to check if there is a circular is imagine if "1" flowing towards "infinity symbol". If the flow does come back to where the first "1" come from, then there is a circular relation.